# Reducing over Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Suppose I have a type defined as:

```
data Node = forall a b. Node (SimpleWire a b)
```

The `SimpleWire` is a monad, where `a` represents the inputs, and `b` represents the outputs. I can do function commposition over that monad. So suppose I have `wireA` of type `SimpleWire A B`, and `wireB` of type `SimpleWire B C`, doing `wireA . wireB` would give me the type `SimpleWire A C`.

Now I want to fold over a list of that monad (so of type `[Node]` for this case). Something like:

```
buildGraph :: [Node] -> (SimpleWire a b)
buildGraph (Node h):t = h . (buildGraph t)
```

How do I make this code work in Haskell's type system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume the following story:

You probably used the type

```
data Node = forall a b. Node (SimpleWire a b)
```

instead of just `SimpleWire a b` because you wanted a list of `SimpleWire`'s where `a` and `b` are different. In particular, what you were really hoping for as the argument to `buildGraph` was something like (in pseudo-Haskell)

```
buildGraph :: [SimpleWire a b, SimpleWire b c, ..., SimpleWire x y] -> SimpleWire a y
```

You couldn't express that first list with Haskell's standard homogeneous `[]` though and tried to use universally-quantified types to get you out of that pickle.

If what I've said is true, you're probably looking for [type-threaded lists or "thrists"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/thrist-0.3.0.2). In particular, you can do away with `Node` altogether. A `Thrist (->) a b` is a list of functions `a -> a1`, `a1 -> a2`, ..., `an -> b`. More generally a `Thrist f a b` is a list of `f`s `f a a1`, `f a1 a2`, ..., `f an b`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import qualified Data.Thrist as DT

-- Note that I'll be using (>>>) as a flipped form of (.), i.e. 
-- (>>>) = flip (.)
-- (>>>) is in fact an Arrow operation which is significantly more general
-- than function composition. Indeed your `SimpleWire` type is almost
-- definitely an arrow.
import Control.Arrow ((>>>))

-- A simple take on SimpleWire
type SimpleWire = (->)

-- Ugh a partial function that blows up if the thrist is empty
unsafeBuildGraph :: DT.Thrist SimpleWire a b -> SimpleWire a b
unsafeBuildGraph = DT.foldl1Thrist (>>>)

-- Making it total
buildGraph :: DT.Thrist SimpleWire a b -> Maybe (SimpleWire a b)
buildGraph DT.Nil = Nothing
buildGraph (wire `DT.Cons` rest) = Just $ DT.foldlThrist (>>>) wire rest

-- For syntactic sugar
(*::*) = DT.Cons
infixr 6 *::*

trivialExample :: DT.Thrist SimpleWire a a
trivialExample = id *::* id *::* DT.Nil

lessTrivialExample :: (Num a, Show a) => DT.Thrist SimpleWire a String
lessTrivialExample = (+ 1) *::* (* 2) *::* show *::* DT.Nil

-- result0 is "12"
result0 = (unsafeBuildGraph lessTrivialExample) 5

-- result1 is Just "12"
result1 = fmap ($ 5) (buildGraph lessTrivialExample)
```

A side note:

Although `SimpleWire` may very well be a monad, that's probably not going to directly help you. In particular while functions are monads, what you seem to care about is generalizing over the notion of function composition, which is what [arrows](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows) are for (and which bear only an indirect relationship to monads). There are hints of this in the fact that I used `>>>` and that `Thrist` has an `Arrow` instance. As I mention in the comments to the code, `SimpleWire` is probably an `Arrow`.

Answer (score 6):

We can not compose `[Node]` with the proposed types. This is because otherwise we would get

```
sw1 :: SimpleWire A B
sw2 :: SimpleWire C D
buildGraph :: [Node] -> (SimpleWire a b)
buildGraph [ sw1, sw2 ] :: SimpleWire E F
```

Which is way too strong. We were able to compose arbitrary, incompatible types (wrong), and then to result with a random write at the very end (wrong).

The problem is that we lost all the type information in the `[Node]` type. We need to remember some, namely:

1. The first and last wire types are known (the intermediate ones are not)
2. In the list, every adjacent node is composable

So, we get a custom GADT list type

```
data NodeList a b where
   Nil  :: NodeList a a
   Cons :: Node a b -> NodeList b c -> NodeList a c
```

And then

```
buildGraph :: NodeList a b -> SimpleWire a b
buildGraph Nil = id  
buildGraph (Cons (Node h) t) = h . buildGraph t
```